# How do I manage session and role together in nodejs?

Tags: node.js

I have session management in my mean stack application, how can I implement role in that session? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Role management can be done multiple ways. Each user is associated with one or more than one role and each role has different permissions.

You need to check those permissions at client side as well as server side while performing any action.

Once user is logged in, you can store roles/permissions in session object for later use at server side. Same way you can pass role/permission to the client immediately after user login. You can store those role/permissions in browser so that you can disable/enable some of the functionalities based on role/permission and keep it in browser till user is logged in.

Suppose admin is changing some role/permission for that user from different session. Then you can use socket on/emit feature to update role/permission in browser and server.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is crisp and clear. If possible can you share any links or samples you have....

Comment: I do not think you will get such links directly, you may have to look for session management and role management separately and club it together as per your need. ....